# How to add a condition to this loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a looping code that will remove all the names starting with the letter "a"
but I'm not sure how to get it to work properly

```js
let friends = ["Adam", "John", "Bernard", "Jacoub", "Arnold", "Kaytlen", "Samir"];
let letter = "a";

for (let i = 0; i < friends.length; i++){
if(friends[i][0] === "A"){
    continue;
}
    console.log(`${i} => ${friends[i]}`);

}
```

The problem is I want to write each index number before the name, but when I use `continue;` it removes the whole thing and I get this output

//"1 => John"

//"2 => Bernard"

//"3 => Jacoub"

//"5 => Kaytlen"

//"6 => Samir"

Notice how index 0, 4 are missing

Comment: Filter the array before looping over it.

Comment: So, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7nwhtypk/)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

When the if statement evaluates to true, the `continue` statement is reached. This statement tells JavaScript to move on to the next iteration of the loop, therefore, the names starting with "A" is not logged to the console.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you want an array containing a list of friends that's name Do Not start with the letter "A", I would suggest using the `filter` array method as @kelly mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
let friends = ["Adam", "John", "Bernard", "Jacoub", "Arnold", "Kaytlen", "Samir"];
let letter = "a";

friends =  friends.filter(function(friend){
  return !friend.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(letter)
})
for (let i = 0; i < friends.length; i++){

    console.log(`${i} => ${friends[i]}`);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with your original code here is one approach:

```
let friends = ["Adam", "John", "Bernard", "Jacoub", "Arnold", "Kaytlen", "Samir"];
let letter = "a";
    
 for(let i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
     if(friends[i][0].toLowerCase() === letter.toLowerCase()) {
         friends.splice(i, 1);
         i--;
     }
     console.log(`${i} => ${friends[i]}`);
 }
```

The reason for the i-- is if there is an adjacent element that also matches the criteria